# Alter a style from a parent

Tags: c#, wpf, scope, styles

I have a custom class that is derived from userControl, it describes what features a "service window" should have. It should also describe how a instance of this "service window" should look.
I have a style called serviceStyle. now whenever i create a new instance of the service window, i have to manually set the style in the XAML of the instance, when possible i want to avoid having to do this by basically forcing the style to all childs of service window to serviceStyle. Then i want to be able to do a fade animation on a textBlock in serviceStyle. Now since this is the style of a child of the "Service window" it seems unreachable...

In the meantime i found a way to Set the Style as a default style for all the service windows, this can be done by adding this line in the constructor:
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(NetcarityService), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(NetcarityService)));

Now i need to be able to get from the source to the element textBlock in the xaml of the ServiceWindowStyle....

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to do that in order to make a default style, you just define your style without a key. For example, this style applies to all button in an app (if the style is defined in app.xaml)

```
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Style.Setters>
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="6"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="6,3,6,3"></Setter>
            </Style.Setters>
        </Style>
```

With regards the children I would think you just need to write some code to detect when a child is added and set the default style for the child. I think you can just override OnVisualChildrenChanged.

PS. Setting DefaultStyleKeyProperty should be done in the static constructor